# How to create laravel5 authentication

Tags: php, laravel-5

How to create laravel 5 authentication. I am upgrading the app from `laravel 4` to `laravel 5` .

In laravel 4, I have used `logincontroller` to authenticate the user using api.

How can I do it in laravel 5.

Comment: What do you try for create Laravel5 auth ? What is your issue for more understand...

Comment: I have one laravel app with all existing functionality. I am upgrading it in laravel 5. there is already login functionality. I just want to convert it in laravel 5. I want all my route will work after login except few. (Sorry for english)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 comes with Auth built-in. Run the following `artisan` command to get Laravel to setup the required controllers and views to handle auth:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Comment: already I have all that functionality. but do you mean I have to create all those things newly.

Comment: You can continue to use your existing code for authentication, or you can refactor your code to use the Laravel 5 auth controller. Take a look at the `app/Http/Controllers/Auth` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The project structure have changed a lot from Laravel 4 to Laravel 5. The controller folder which was initially in app/ director now moved to app/http/Controller directory and so on. So all your old code structure need to be refactored in order to work with Laravel 5. 
You can cross-check if you didn't miss anything while upgrading by this 
http://www.sitepoint.com/laravel-4-laravel-5-simple-upgrade-guide/ .